# SAS hash table - multivalues for single key and find_next

Tags: hash, sas, key, hashtable, key-value

I am using a hash table to look up values and determine whether there is a match. These are the testing codes.

What I am trying to do is to check whether students in `roster` have entries in `grade_roster`; if a student has entries in `grade_roster`, I attach that `grade_on_report` to a new dataset that is the dup of `roster`.

`name` is my key and the grades are values. One name may have several grades, i.e. multivalues for a single key. I was able to find all names in the `roster` that have a match in `grade_roster` using `find_next()`, but I could not attach the right grade to the new dataset.

It seems like whenever `find_next()` is called, the value for the key was set to the next item in the list, and therefore assign that value to all previous keys.

Here is my code:

```
data roster;
input name $ course $ grade_on_paper $;
  datalines;
  Mary English A
  Mary German B
  Josh English B
  Lily Spanish B
  Lucy Physics C
  John Music A
  Eric Math A
  Eric Music B
;
run;

data grade_roster;
input name $ course $ grade_on_report $;
  datalines;
  Mary English A
  Mary German B
  John Music A
  Eric Math A
  Eric Music B
;
run;

data assign_grade;
  set roster;
  format grade_on_report $1.;

  declare hash ht1(dataset:"grade_roster", multidata:"Y");
  ht1.defineKey("name");
  ht1.defineData("grade_on_report");
  ht1.defineDone();

  rc = ht1.find();
  do while(rc = 0);
    rc = ht1.find_next();
  end;
run;
```

What I got was this:

```
    name    course  grade_on_paper  grade_on_report name_found      
1   Mary    English        A           B            Y   
2   Mary    German         B           B            Y               
3   Josh    English        B                        
4   Lily    Spanish        B                        
5   Lucy    Physics        C                        
6   John    Music          A           A            Y       
7   Eric    Math           A           B            Y       
8   Eric    Music          B           B            Y
```

What I want is:

```
    name    course  grade_on_paper  grade_on_report name_found      
1   Mary    English        A           A            Y   
2   Mary    German         B           B            Y               
3   Josh    English        B                        
4   Lily    Spanish        B                        
5   Lucy    Physics        C                        
6   John    Music          A           A            Y       
7   Eric    Math           A           A            Y       
8   Eric    Music          B           B            Y
```

Note: `name` and `course` together are not unique identifiers. It seems like they are unique identifiers in this particular test code but they are not unique identifiers in the actual dataset I am working on. The goal is to use `name` as the only key in `ht1.defineKey()` and get the correct result.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: If there are multiple matches for the same key(s), which match do you want to use? The first one found? The last? Some other rule?

Comment: I want to use the corresponding match determined by other columns in the dataset. In this test code is determined by `course`. For example, for Mary (the key) in English class, I found a first match of Mary with grade (the value) A in English class, then I would attach that value and not step down to the next value. If however, the first match is Mary in German class, then I would continue to step down until I find the value that is in English class and then attach that. Hope I make everything clear.

Comment: What if there are multiple matches for the combination of name and course? Is any ok?

Comment: You just remind me of the solution. I would just need to add couple if else statements inside the do while loop and that will do. Thanks for the enlightenment!

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to find data on a specific student and course, you need to make both `name` and `course` part of the key.

```
data assign_grade;
  set roster;
  format grade_on_report $1.;

  declare hash ht1(dataset:"grade_roster", multidata:"Y");
  ht1.defineKey("name", "course");
  ht1.defineData("grade_on_report");
  ht1.defineDone();

  rc = ht1.find();
  do while(rc = 0);
    rc = ht1.find_next();
  end;
run
```

I tested this on sligthly different data

```
data roster;
input name $ course $ grade_on_paper $;
  datalines;
  Mary English A
  Mary German B
  Josh English B
  Lily Spanish B
  Lucy Physics C
  John Music A
  Eric Math A
  Eric Music B
;
run;

data grade_roster;
input name $ course $ grade_on_report $;
  datalines;
  Mary German B
  Mary English A
  John Music A
  Eric Math C
  Eric Music B
;
run;
```

and got what I expected.